# How to find out where a certain subdirectory is mounted?

Tags: files, mount

Let's say that `/var/log` is `/dev/sda2`, and `/var/spool` is part of `/var` which is  part of `/` which is `/dev/sda1`.

Now I'd like to issue a command like

```
$ sudo get_mountpoint_of /var/spool
```

and get the correct answer:

```
/var/spool is part of / and is mounted on /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a particular directory is mounted?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151390/how-to-check-a-particular-directory-is-mounted)

Answer (score 2):

on a linux system you can do:

```
findmnt -nvoSOURCE -T /*some/path
```

...to print only the source-device for whatever file is referred to by `/*some/path`.

---

options breakdown:

---

- `-n`

  - omits column headings
- `-oSOURCE`

  - selects only the *`SOURCE`* device output column, though there are many others.
  - append `,TARGET` to list the mount-point column as well.
- `-v`

  - omits the *`[...]`* portion of any possible *`/dev/device[/bindmnt]`* result
- `-T`

  - instructs `findmnt` to work backwards through its `--target` argument until it finds a valid mount-point before reporting.

---

for more information:

```
man findmnt
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `sudo` to do this.  You could write a script which did "df" for the starting point, and read the mount point from the output.  If the mount point is not "/", then your script would recur, asking where *that* was mounted.

For instance, on the machine at hand, I have

```
$ df /var/log
Filesystem                                             1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-uuid/8a1efcd1-0d32-4674-aa7a-c24c2cd924fd  19751804 12437492   6310948  67% /
```

For generality, your script would have to recognize that (for this example), the disk information may be managed by LVM or udev, and getting details for *that* likely requires `sudo`).

The case posed by OP is simpler of course.  For the same machine, I have a filesystem on a disk device:

```
$ df /users
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        8255928 5548304   2288248  71% /users
```

and again, the script would only have to look at the output of "df" to see whether to finish, or recur, asking where *that* was mounted.

Answer (score 1):

For mountpoint info

```
df -P file/goes/here | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

For "part of" info

```
df /mountpointFromTheLastCommand | tail -1 | awk '{print $6}'
```

Example :

```
[root@xxx ~]# df -P /root/download/ | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1
/dev/sda2
[root@xxx ~]# df /dev/sda2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $6}'
/
```

And with these informations, you can say /root/download is part of / and is mounted on /dev/sda2 =]

This is the idea, you can optimize it and make it in one line with your output you want.